# How to run eval spawn ssh and expect in background?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcl, expect

I created a script to get in inside an Access Point (AP) using `ssh` and execute some commands and I used `expect` to interact with shell.

The scripts works fine when it is running on foreground, but when I try to execute the same script in background using `&` to fork the process, it stop at `spawn ssh` command at `ap_commands` script below.

Trying to execute:

```
$ run_ap &
```

Bash script (`run_ap`) to call the expect script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while(true); do
    /script/ap_commands
done
```

Tcl and expect script (`ap_commands`):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@192.168.92.1

#use correct prompt
set prompt ":|#|\\\>"
set user   ">"

interact -o -nobuffer -re "Password:" return
send "pass12345\r"
```

## Update 1 - Solution

Thanks to Donal Fellows, I solved using the screen command who it creates a new terminal and execute the script in foreground.

```
screen -dm bash ./run_ap
```

and I add `-f` arguments to `expect`, to force to run in foreground:

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `interact` command will *not* work with a backgrounded script, since it explicitly expects to *interact* with the user (as well as the `spawn`ed subprocess); when the `interact` happens, if the process isn't in the foreground, the OS gives it a signal (SIGTSTP) that makes stop and wait for the user to make it a foreground process. This is usual Unix terminal handling.

If you want to use backgrounding, you need to stick to `expect`ing things.